# What plant is this? Does anyone know name

Tags: identification

Can anyone please tell me what plant is this?

[image: Pot plant with long narrow leaves]

Answer (score 2):

It's called Yucca, and it originates from central America. It is a very tough houseplant, it doesn't need much water nor light. However, they will look healthier and thrive better when given a lot of light.

Be careful not to give it too much water, that can kill your plant.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that's a yucca. Its leaves do not appear toothed and they're much floppier than any yucca I've ever seen, but I'm in North America so who knows. Do you have a species name or corroborating link that will confirm? Looks more like an agapanthus to me.

Comment: It is a Yucca  - there are spiky tips or thorns on the leaf tips, where they've not been cut off. These are not present on Agapanthus. There are several different varieties of Yucca, some of which have softer,floppier leaves. @Rohma a Unless you live somewhere with an unsuitable climate, this will grow outdoors in my experience.

Comment: I don't think it's a yucca, at least none of the varieties I've seen in SoCal. Normally yucca have very firm leaves that are erect. However looking on the wikipedia for yucca does address this particular species: Yucca flaccida Haw; which apparently do droop.

Comment: The leaves look exactly the same as the the leaves on my own Yucca houseplant plant. Same shape, same color. I have a *Yucca elephantipes*, so I think it is very likely the same species.

Comment: It's very common that yucca as houseplant starts to [droop](https://patgarden.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Why-Does-My-Yucca-Cane-Have-Yellow-Leaves.jpg) after a while.

Comment: @benn The Y. elephantipes I've seen online all have very pointed leaves, not like the chubbier leaves on this plant (looking at the leaves that still have their thorn at the ends). It was good to see, though, that some of the potted plants droop in the manner shown in the OP's photo. Probably a yucca, but possibly not Y. elephantipes. Perhaps a hybrid? Natural variety? Perhaps I'm flat-out wrong ? :)

Comment: @Jurp, I have these *Y. elephantipes* plants for 20 years now, had many cuttings and also I have seen this plant very often in other houses and offices (it is one of the most popular house plants here in the Netherlands). I didn't guess based on online pictures, but know from experience that this is *Y. elephantipes*. If you don't want to believe me it is fine, no problem!

Comment: @benn No issues, benn. As noted in my comment, I could be flat-out wrong, which I'm sure I am here. For other readers' future reference, though, I think you should post photos/cultural information in your answer so that it can be used by others with a similar question to verify their own plants. Whenever I make an ID from experience, I always post links or my own photos for that reason. Bamboo seems to do the same with their answers, too.

Comment: Isn't this a spider lily? It will bloom with white lily flowers with good fragrance.